# DHCP not working in Voice Vlan

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, dhcp, voice

Description:

I have an Admin Network which primarly which provides services for admin data (Company) Service Vlan 1-100 & IP telephony services (Two Vlan 200 & 250). This network is now upgraded in terms on capacity & IP Telephony (from analog to telephony) due to this current voice vlan 200 which is in /24 subnet (200 users) need to switched to new & bigger subnet (New Voice Vlan 250).

Users connected to New Voice Vlan should be on DHCP & PC connected on Phone should work on default serices vlan port.

Issue:

- Can we configure two Voice vlans on cisco switch?
- To work in IP Phone Plus PC setup , Do the Phone should have static IP configuration?
- Do ASA firewall is stopping DORA process ? However AVAYA server is on
  LAN.
- I tried replacing voice vlan VLAN 200 to VLAN 250 on interface
  , all users (Phone , PC) connected that port are registering in
  default vlan ie VLAN 1 . I have configured that same port with VLAN
  250 as access VLAN , Phone is able to get IP configuration but PC is
  not working ?

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question to include the network device configurations.

Comment: Make sure that the DHCP request and offers are taking the same path and it is not asynchronous.  If ASA sees replies but no offers, it will drop the traffic by its default global security policy.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the port set to 
switchport mode access
and 
switchport access vlan 250
your PC should grab the correct DHCP address.

Yes, you should be able to have 2 voice VLANs.  https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10211171/multiple-voice-vlans-call-manager

ASA is not blocking DORA unless your DHCP server is off of your LAN somewhere, but I'm guessing you are serving DHCP from the Avaya.

Ensure dhcp-helper on your Access Switch (2960) is setup.  It should be since you have two VLANs already.

And...Ensure that you have added the new DHCP scope on your DHCP server.

Comment: Issue: LLDP was disable on Cisco Switch. By enabling LLDP Phones were getting IP address & configuration files.

Comment: @FaizanNizam, please post that as an answer and accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.